# Change the number of columns in scrreprt without multicols?

Tags: koma-script, two-column, multicol

I have a small problem with `scrreprt`. I use the `twocolumn` option for the whole document, which works great. However for the supporting information part of my thesis it would be much better to just have one column page. I tried doing this with the package `multicol`, but then all my floats did not work (which seems to be unsolvable with `multicol`, as a read on this page). Can somebody help me with this? How do I get the best out of both worlds.

I am also wondering if there's a possibility to have floats which span two columns, so e. g. if I have a image which should stretch the whole page not just one half of it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\onecolumn` to get one column page(s) and `\twocolumn` to switch back. Note that both commands starts a new page. To have a float using both columns use the starred version of the floating environments. Note that they will not be on the first page.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\begin{figure*}
  \rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure*}
\Blindtext

\onecolumn
\addchap{Supporting information}
\Blindtext[2]
\twocolumn

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: its always so simple, im sorry i missed that! I will try this out tomorrow, thanks alot!

Comment: jap, worked perfectly as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for providing this simple solution!